# Assigning new field values based on ifelse logic with lag/lead function in R

Tags: r, if-statement, lag

Have seen several posts on this, but can't seem to get it to work for my specific use case.

I'm trying to assign a new field value based on ifelse logic.  My input dataset looks like:

[image: Input dataset]

If the value for X is missing, I am trying to replace it with the previous value of X, only when the value of `unique_id` is the same as the previous value of `unique_id`.  I would like the output dataset to look like this:

[image: Output dataset]

The code I've written (I'm a total beginner) doesn't throw an error, but the data doesn't change:

```
within(data3, data3$Output <- ifelse(data3$unique_id == lag(data3$unique_id) & is.na(data3$Output), data3$Output == lag(data3$Output), data3$Output == data3$Output))
```

I do change missing data values ("-") in the input dataset to official `NA` missing values in a previous step... hopefully allowing me to use the `is.na` function.

Comment: If you're open to other suggestions, the [`fill()` function from the tidyr package](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html) is designed for this type of task. Worth checking it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could group the IDs, then use `fill` to copy down the values replacing NAs by group. See the reproducible example below.

(If you have NAs which could appear before or after the value, then you could add `, .direction = "downup"` to the `fill`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
df <- tribble(
  ~unique_id, ~x, ~mom,
  "m", 73500, 4,
  "m", NA, 0,
  "z", 4000, 5,
  "z", NA, 0,
)

df2 <- df |> 
  group_by(unique_id) |> 
  fill(x, .direction = "downup") |> 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   unique_id     x   mom
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 m         73500     4
#> 2 m         73500     0
#> 3 z          4000     5
#> 4 z          4000     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you - this works great.  The actual data frame, however, seems to still contain the original values.  How do I read the new values into the data frame?

Comment: Just insert `df2 <-` before the `df |>` to save the updated dataframe as df2.

Comment: Thank you again - that works :)  This code works when the NA comes after the value (e.g. 73500, 4000).  I'm having some trouble getting it to work when the NA comes before the value.  I need it to do both.  Thoughts?

Comment: Add `, .direction = "downup"` to the `fill`.  See update above.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` option where you replace the `NA` with the `non-NA` value per group:

```r
df <- data.frame(unique_id = c("m", "m"),
                 X = c(73500, NA),
                 MoM = c("4%", "0%"))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, X := X[!is.na(X)][1L], by = unique_id]
df
#>    unique_id     X MoM
#> 1:         m 73500  4%
#> 2:         m 73500  0%
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This works great, but when I try to aggregate the resulting data frame, I get an error message:

Comment: Error in `[.data.table`(pdata, c("Output", "MoM")) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.

Comment: When I run the aggregation code without running your code, it runs fine, no error message.

Comment: pdata_agg <- aggregate(x = df[c("Output","MoM")],
                          by = df[c("Provinces","Yearly","Weekly","Unit","Product","Component", "unique_key")],
                          FUN = mean)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the provided solutions: One of these:

### `fill()`

suggest by @jared_marot in the comments

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  fill(X)
```

### `first()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(unique_id) %>% 
  mutate(X = first(X))
```

### `lag()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(unique_id) %>% 
  mutate(X = lag(X, default = X[1]))
```

### base R

```
df[2,2] <- df[1,2]
```